# Visual Studio for Mac Stuck on "Finishing Installation"

Tags: visual-studio

I downloaded Visual Studio professional edition for my Mac. The installer runs until it's all but done, however it hangs on the "Finishing Installation" stage.

[Screenshot of installation window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4DSk.png)

Comment: I don't consider this an answer, but here's what I did and it worked:
1) Cancelled install
2) Trash whatever droppings were in the /Applications folder from the cancelled install
3) Rebooted
4) After reboot, stop all non-essential services.  In my case, this was virus scanner (I bet that was the culprit), Google Drive, Google Photos, Dropbox
5) Ran install again

Worthy of note, I had the Beta installed and forgot all about it.  I removed that, too, on the second attempt.  That also could have been the problem.

Comment: I also had Visual Studio Code installed.  Removed that, too.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: As it turned out, it was a matter of waiting. The top answer claimed they had to wait 10-15 minutes; I ended up having to wait over an hour, but it installed in the end.

Comment: @everybody0523 (just a guess) possibly the speed reflects your PC specs

Answer (score 8):

Had the same situation today after my VS failed to update and needed a complete clean install. During the installation process it was stuck on "Finishing installation... (still going...)", but after 10-15mins it started asking for my user password multiple times and finished the install. Everything working as expected. Take a cup of coffee and relax is my advice to everyone else experiencing this :)

---

EDIT: I found multiple sources claiming it takes up to 30 minutes and even up to an hour for installation to finish. My guess is that PC specs also have to do with installation speed, mine was on MacBook Pro Mid 2015. Anyways, everybody has their VS installed after waiting for some time, so patience is the key.

Comment: Same advice on Windows as well :)

Comment: What could the installer possibly be doing that takes so long?  The wait would be less aggravating if it at least provided some information about what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My system hung at the Finishing installation (still going) part as well, but it hung at the Installing Android SDK bit. It seemed that I had installed Android Studio previously on my Mac, but I hadn't uninstalled the Android SDK from the Applications directory along with it which I think hung the process. I stopped the installation, deleted the Android SDK directory from the Applications directory then rebooted, re-started installation and it all went through fine. SO maybe look for previously installed bits and pieces...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Mine was stuck at Finishing Installation stage for 4~6 hours; I tried all above/below solutions, but nothing worked for me. But what I figured out later was that the software was successfully installed, but their installation page had an error and never showed that it has been finished. Try opening the Visual Studio and creating a test file. It might be fully installed already.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and it turned out to be because of the Antivirus. Uninstall or disable your AV

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the installation log, my install hung here:

```
[2019-02-11 19:59:13.934] [Info] Software item 'Android SDK' installed successfully.
[2019-02-11 19:59:13.934] [Info] Status: successful
[2019-02-11 19:59:13.935] [Info] Skipping installation of software item 'Intel® HAXM'
```

It had been hanging there for an entire episode of *Homecoming*, so, after reading this and looking around a bit, I just launched Visual Studio, and it appears to be working.